# How to evaluate test error on kmeans algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm trying to understand how it is possible to evaluate the error (1 - R^2) on a test set not used for the training in a kmeans algorithm. In particular, after this model definition

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, n_init=10, random_state=rs)
kmeans.fit(Xtrain)
```

I learnt a linear model for each cluster, and computed the error thanks to this function

```
(1-lr.score(cluster, Y_cluster))
```

Now, I'd like to see the same error applied on a test set, so, searching online, I found out that the .predict(Xtest) function is helpful to link each element of the test set to its relative cluster. Also I noticed that all the values returned are or 0 or 3.
From now on I'm stuck on how to compute the error with the score() function reported above, I tried with the (Xtest[kmeans.labels_==i] but it returns me errors. Any help?